# Yii 2 id зарегестрированного пользователя использовать в игре

Tags: yii2

хочу написать простенькую рпг.

пользуюсь yii 2 user, который с ходу создает 7 таблиц.

при этом все это в модуле user

хочу игру закинуть в modules\game

по логике можно бы и 2 базы иметь - под игру и под юзера, но тогда внешние ключи не будут работать.

как быть? можно ли пробросить связь между модулями? или просто создать в модуле модель my_user и при первой регистрации создавать под пользователя запись с его ид и именем?

как это правильно реализуется?

Comment: Например в `game` в нужной модели модели пишется геттер `public function getUser() { return $this->hasOne('app\modules\users\models\User', array('id' => 'user_id')); }` ... так как во второй `yii` связи сделаны как сеттеры и геттеры ... вот гляньте тоже самое чел говорит: http://habrahabr.ru/post/185236/

Answer (score 1):

C помощью переопределения метода `getDb` объекта `ActiveRecord` можно выбрать компонент, который будет использован для соединения с бд. Соответственно релейшены у вас будут работать нормально.

Я советую вам использовать одну бд и либо наследоваться от компонента и расширять его, либо отказаться и сделать реализацию исключительно под свои нужды.